# Dependency error in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Here's the error:

[image: error]

Here my build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: [edit] your question and insert all relevant error messages, scripts etc as text instead of as images.

Comment: always target sdk version larger than minimum sdk version..........make target version is 23

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   compileSdkVersion 23

   targetSdkVersion 23 

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the appcompat dependency to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes-

In your appcompat dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code is on the wrong line:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
}
```

Java will not recognize or read your code until you cut and paste it into the correct line.

`compileOptions` goes in the line before the last closing curly bracket directly below `buildTypes` as seen below:

[image: Image 1]

Also, directly after "v7", your version is not properly referenced. It needs to look like this line below:

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"

(not shown in screenshot)